# MicrosoftIdentityWebApi Not Working for Web Application when Added in Startup

Tags: c#, azure-ad-b2c, webapi, microsoft-identity-web, aad-b2c

I'm adding this question because I struggled for a while to find this and wanted to add a reference here for anyone pulling their hair out over the same issue.

While hooking up Azure B2C I struggled trying to get the backend to be able to read the claims in the token coming from Azure. I verified the token was valid and should have claims with the help of jwt.io and example applications and I setup my application to read the token but every time my application attempted to read the claims in AuthorizationHandlerContext.User.Identity.Claims they were always empty.

Investigating further, it became clear that in Startup.cs the authentication that I setup was never being hit.

The following line was being hit:

```
Services
   .AddAuthentication(*some schema*)
   .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
   {
      //set some options
   }, options =>
   {
      //set some options
   })
```

But the code that actually set the options was never being hit.

If you're experiencing a similar issue see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that buried in my startup base class was this line from the previous authentication implementation:

```
services.AddIdentity<SomeUserClass, IdentityRole>();
```

Once that was removed I was able to receive the claims in the format that Azure B2C was sending them and integrate into my application.